# PHP - filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given

Tags: php

I am developing a PHP site for someone, it works perfectly fine locally on my own webserver. I pushed it to the remote host and now I get:

> **Warning**:  filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long, string
>   given

at this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <?php 
        $page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

        if (isset($page)) {
            echo "var page = '$page';";
        } else {
            echo "var page = 'home.html';";
        }
    ?>
</script>
```

This happens with the code if the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in <b>/home/kraeuterelfe-de/htdocs/neueSeite/index.php</b> on line <b>68</b><br />
var page = 'home.html';    </script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

I don't know why it throws this error, since `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` is not a string.

My local webserver runs `PHP 7.1.1` while the remote webserver runs 5.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why it throws this error, since FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS is not a string.
>
> My local webserver runs PHP 7.1.1 while the remote webserver runs 5.2.6

According to this comment, http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php#111398, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS was added with PHP version 5.3.3.

The function expects a long value as second parameter, but the constant FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS does not exist yet when you run this code under PHP 5.2.6, so PHP does what it always does when it encounters an undefined constant - it assumes you actually meant it to be a *string*/text literal containing the constant name as text. (You should also have gotten a "Notice: Use of undefined constant FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS - assumed 'FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS' in [...]", at least if you have PHP configured to display notices as well.)

That's the explanation for the specific error message,

> filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given

---

As you mentioned in your own answer, you found a workaround/alternate solution already, so I'm adding this for explanation only.

You might want to specify the charset as well with htmlspecialchars though, because http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php:

> PHP 5.4 and 5.5 will use UTF-8 as the default. Earlier versions of PHP use ISO-8859-1.

So under 5.2.6, you might want to specify UTF-8, assuming your app/site uses that; otherwise that can have some security implications.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following info on [php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.sanitize.php):

> FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS -> Equivalent to calling
>   htmlspecialchars() with ENT_QUOTES set.

So I changed

```
$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

to

```
$page = htmlspecialchars($_GET['page'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Now it works again.

Comment: `filter_input` will return `null` if `$_GET['page']` is not set, but your replacement line will yield `NOTICE Undefined index`. Also, if `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` is not defined, PHP will interpret it as a string constant of the same value while yielding `NOTICE Use of undefined constant FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS`. Check your `error_reporting` you may have some hidden bugs/vulnerabilities.